# CSS alignment different for Mobile and Desktop view

Tags: html, css

I have this layout :

```css
.biggest {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: teal;
  float: left;
}

.section1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
}

.inside1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  background: deeppink;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inside2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  background: forestgreen;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="biggest"></div>
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="inside1"></div>
    <div class="inside2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to align boxes in this order :pink, teal, and green on mobile view. How to do that?

The white box is to keep the inside boxes together. I am facing problems while aligning elements inside columns in different order as boxes inside column can't be separated. If anyone have idea how to do that, an explanation would be a great help.

Comment: vertical or horizontal?

Comment: @DCR I want them to stack vertically in the order mentioned.

Comment: Is changing the html an option ?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately because of the way you aligned them it's not possible for you to put `.biggest` between `.inside1` and `.inside2` because `.biggest` is the reletive of their parent `.section1` which with simple html and css you cant say for monitors be out of `.section1` and for mobiles be inside `.section1` though there is a nasty way which i dont recommend it 
you can do this with js first you should get the element  and save it in a variable then try to remove it from where it is and then add it to next to  `.inside1` also you can use jquery and try `.detach()` and `.append()` to detach an element and append it to somewhere else you can read more about it in [here](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

By using the grid layout and a media query for the mobile screen you can achieve this.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
}

.teal {
  background: teal;
  grid-row: 1 / -1
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .pink {
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  .teal {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="teal"></div>
  <div class="pink"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you to solve the problem.

Here's the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/MWwLywm?editors=1100).

Answer (score 0):

When `inside1` and `inside2` are in a different parent container, this isn't possible. However, one solution is to have all three elements under one parent container, and then use CSS Grid to build the two-column layout as well as re-order at a different screen size.

Here's a CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/samsonzhangthesalmon/pen/qBdgZdy

Unlike @Prathamesh Koshti's answer, mine preserves the heights of the pink and green blocks using `min-content` in the grid.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content minmax(min-content, 1fr);
}

.biggest {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.inside1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: deeppink;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inside2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: forestgreen;
  margin: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* example of mobile */
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    /* reset to one column. Better than doing this is to put the two-column line in a min-width: 600px query and go mobile-first, but for the sake of clarity I'll overwrite it here */
  }
  .biggest {
    grid-row: 2/3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="biggest"></div>
  <div class="inside1"></div>
  <div class="inside2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1- always try to use the simplest html and css - makes it a lot easier to debug
2- there's a trick here.  notice how I had to reorder the div's in the html.  In this way I can make use of the float property but also have the div's listed in the correct mobile order.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.biggest {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: teal;
  float: left;
}

.inside1,
.inside2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background: pink;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.inside2{
   background:green;
   }

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .biggest,
  .inside1,
  .inside2 {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inside1"></div>
<div class="biggest"></div>
<div class="inside2"></div>
```

Comment: *I want to align boxes in this order: pink, teal, and green*

Comment: just change the color of inside2 to green